# Datatable no funciona boton siguiente de la paginación

Tags: datatable, paginacion, server-side-rendering, server-side

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy teniendo problema con el botón siguiente, que no funciona. Este código debería iniciar la tabla y mostrar el botón siguiente, muestra el botón, pero el mismo no funciona, no lleva al la siguiente opción de paginación.

```
function tableInit(){

$('#tbl_solicitud_devolucion_all').dataTable().fnDestroy()
$('#tbl_solicitud_devolucion_all').DataTable({
        "ajax":
            $.fn.dataTable.pipeline( {
                "url": $("input#base_url").val()+"api/solicitud/getSolicitudesDevolucionPaginada?estado=0,1,2,4",
            "type" : "GET",
            "pages": 5,
            }),
        "lengthMenu": [
            [5, 10, 15, 25, 50],
            [5, 10, 15, 25, 50],
            
        ],
        "language": {
            sProcessing: "Procesando...",
            sLengthMenu: "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            sZeroRecords: "No se encontraron resultados",
            sEmptyTable: "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
            sInfo: "Del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ reg.",
            sInfoEmpty: "0 registros",
            sInfoFiltered: "(filtrado de _MAX_ reg.)",
            sInfoPostFix: "",
            sSearch: "Buscar:",
            sUrl: "",
            sInfoThousands: ",",
            sLoadingRecords: "Cargando...",
            //sDom: "tlip",
            oPaginate: {
                sFirst: "Primero",
                sLast: "Último",
                sNext: "Sig",
                sPrevious: "Ant"
            },
            oAria: {
                sSortAscending:
                ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                sSortDescending:
                ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
            }
        },
        
        'iDisplayLength': 10,
        'paging':true,
        'info':true,
        "searching": false, 
        "processing":true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "order": [[ 2, "desc" ]],
```

Comment: _No funciona_: ¿qué comportamiento tiene? ¿cuál es el esperado? ¿qué código tienes hasta el momento? Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, lee [ask] y pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias, ahi agregue parte del codigo para configurar la tabla paginada.